# Add Custom Font for Flutter Web Only

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

How do you add custom font for Web only?

I know that I can add font assets but I'd like to keep using system fonts for ios and android.

Do I embed `<link>` for google fonts in the `<head>` in index.html?

For example:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to use a Google font, the https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts package can defer loading a font until runtime.  If you determine you're on the web, load the font and select it in your primary text theme.  Otherwise, ignore all that. :)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about `google_fonts` package. I ended up doing this: `ThemeData(textTheme: kIsWeb ? GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme() : null)`